# Need to know which keys are accessed more frequently

Tags: redis

Is there a simple way to know from my whole DB which keys are accessed more frequently? Maybe with command OBECT FREQ? https://redis.io/commands/object
But I can't run the command on every key...

Answer (score 0):

`OBJECT FREQ` is indeed the way to go, and you can [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) your database's keyspace and call it on each key.

That said, redis-cli already implements this (SCAN + FREQ) pattern when invoked with the `--hotkeys` switch, i.e.:

```
$ redis-cli --hotkeys

# Scanning the entire keyspace to find hot keys as well as
# average sizes per key type.  You can use -i 0.1 to sleep 0.1 sec
# per 100 SCAN commands (not usually needed).
...
```

Comment: Many thanks Itamar! 
However I cannot run FREQ flag. It tells me that this option is not valid. 
`jirene@sv5apicredis05.:~$ redis-cli -p 6384 object freq  foo
(error) ERR Syntax error. Try OBJECT (refcount|encoding|idletime)` 
The other OBJECT options are ok though `jirene@sv5apicredis05.:~$ redis-cli -p 6384 object idletime foo
(integer) 162`
I'm running redis_version:3.0.7 (yes, I know, I suck..), but there is no mention on the website about FREQ flag not available on this version...

Comment: `FREQ` was added in v4 as part of the LFU eviction policy